# How do I root my galaxy S 9 +

Tags: rooting, 8.0-oreo

I need help, I have tried a few things like towlroot, but  it wont let it install. I download  the apk file then on the permissions i clicked ok then install this is protected by Google play. Then if i keep trying to install it, it just keeps saying app not installed

Comment: What do you mean with "won't let it install"? Could you describe what you saw to us?

Answer (score 0):

1.Enable Developer Option (settings - about phone - Software information - Tap 7 times on build number to activate developer option in settings menu)

2.Enable OEM Unlock from developer option (Currently no workaround for those who doesn't have this option)

3.Download and copy [G965F_root_OEM_issue_devices_V* .zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=5862345805528066589) to Ext SD card

4.[Download TWRP for S9+](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s9-plus/development/twrp-samsung-s9-t3763539)

5.Switch Off device

6.Press Vol down + Bixby + Power to reboot to download mode, press volume up when asked to continue to download mode

7.Download [Odin](https://www.filesbeast.net/file/YHtfY) and open it, Disable 'Auto reboot' from option menu of Odin

8.Select TWRP (tar image) with AP tab of Odin and Start

9.Once Successfully flashed, you will see 'Passed' in Odin tab

10.Disconnect device and hold Vol down + power till screen goes off, Now immediately press Vol Up + Bixby + Power to reboot to TWRP

11.Select to allow modification

12.From TWRP, Select WIPE menu - Then FORMAT DATA - You need to type 'yes' to perform wipe. WARNING : This will erase all data including Int SD storage from device

13.Once format device completes, go back and select REBOOT' Menu and then - 'RECOVERY', This will reboot to TWRP again

14.Now select Install and navigate path to Ext SD card - N965F_root_OEM_issue_devices.zip, you have copied earlier, select desired root method and select 'OEM Patch' option if your device have OEM issue. If you are not sure about this then better select 'OEM Patch', this will prevent losing OEM unlock option and so prevent 'custom binary error'

15. Select one of rooting method in aroma (superSu/Magisk)
16. For SuperSU to work select kernel option (patch stock kernel)

17.Once flash successfully finish, Reboot to System
If you have selected Magisk then Magisk app may appear in drawer after one reboot.

Open settings - Developer option - Look for OEM Unlock option. If it is there, it is safe to reboot device.